# Windows App, Window Dimensions

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I'm developing a Windows Store App and I'm struggling with a really simple problem. How do I statically change the size of the App Window?
I.e., I want my app to start execution using the exact dimension size that I specified in the code. How can I do that?

I tried specifying values for the Width/Height property of the MainPage.xaml but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the startup size can be achieved by using the PreferredLaunchViewSize attribute of the ApplicationView. However, keep in mind that the user can always resize the app afterwards.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
     public MainPage()
     {
     this.InitializeComponent();

     // Set the preferred launch view size to 360 * 550
     ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size { Height = 550, Width = 360 };
     ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
     }
}
```